# for nested loop in php

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I need an explanation about nested for loop in PHP, can you explain the code below how does it work why is the result is that:

```
for ($a=0; $a < 10; $a++) { 
    for ($b=0; $b < 10; $b++) { 
        echo $b;
        echo $a;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here? $a loops from 0 to 9, so does $b. $b loops for each time $a loops, so you'd get 0001020304050607080910111213141516171819 etc.

Comment: It effectively prints the cartesian product of [0, 10) with itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make two changes to your code so that this is easier to explain. The first change is that `$b` iterates to 5 instead of 10. The second change is that the `echo` has been formatted so that you don't just get a mess of numbers when you run the code. Try running this:

```
for ($a = 0; $a < 10; $a++) { 
    for ($b = 0; $b < 5; $b++) { 
        echo "a = ".$a.", b = ".$b."<br>\n";
    }
}
```

What is going on is that `$b` counts to 5, then `$a` increases by 1, and `$b` goes back down to 0. This happens 10 times because `$a` counts to 10. Here is the result of the first few iterations:

```
a = 0, b = 0
a = 0, b = 1
a = 0, b = 2
a = 0, b = 3
a = 0, b = 4
a = 1, b = 0
a = 1, b = 1
a = 1, b = 2
a = 1, b = 3
a = 1, b = 4
a = 2, b = 0
a = 2, b = 1
a = 2, b = 2
a = 2, b = 3
a = 2, b = 4
a = 3, b = 0
a = 3, b = 1
…and so on…
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 for loops.

The first runs the inner second loop 10x.

In every run of the outer loop, the inner loop runs also 10x.

Also the inner loop outputs the vars $b and $a.